# How to cause the VMware window to be opened full screen?

Tags: windows-7, vmware

Due to [this long and honorable thread](https://superuser.com/questions/296407/a-better-way-to-run-vmware) I was able to launch a VM from a separate window, helping by the `vmware-vmrc.exe` utility. The magic works for me! Now (if possible) I'd like to have the window to be opened full screen.

Is this possible? If yes, how can I do it?