# How can I pin shorcuts with arguments to the start menu on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I know that it's possible to [drag and drop a shortcut onto the taskbar](https://superuser.com/a/193255/265814) in Windows 10, but when I try to do the same thing with the Start Menu, I can't find the shortcut. That is, if I simply drag and drop the shortcut onto the start menu icon, it's not visible after opening the start menu. If I drag the shortcut over the start menu icon and wait for the menu to open, the red "cancel" icon is always present.

My motivation for doing this is to save space on the taskbar.

Is this actually possible with Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Right click the shortcut and select Pin to Start. I just tested this with a Hello World batch file. Worked great.

Make your batch file:

```
echo Hello World!
Pause
```

Create your shortcut (per the link you posted). Right click the shortcut and click `Pin to Start`.